# How to add from pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a table in Excel, and I've managed to create a pivot table, which includes "grouping".

What I'm trying to do, is sum the group

My pivot table data looks like

[image]

What I'd like to have is a sum for each 'group', where a group is each 2 rows, the parent being the town.

In otherwords, this is 1 group/row

```
Arrington    School        12600           25
             R             6946.2          22
```

What I'm trying to do is to sum the miles per year, and the time taken by group. So, something like (although where the summed data is displayed isn't too important)

```
Arrington    School        12600           25
             R             6946.2          22
                           19546.2         47
```

Where that new bottom row is the sum of the 2 value above. This would repeat for each group/row in the pivot table.

I don't seem to be able to achieve this because when I click on Field Settings in the Rows pane (after selecting the pivot table)... What do I need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you right click on one of the towns you can choose subtotal which gives you what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this just adds another row but doesn't total the Miles per Year or the Time taken

Comment: It seams that you dont have Miles per Year an Time taken specified as Values. Put them in the lower right Box.